# Lucene: FastVectorHighlighter returns null

Tags: java, lucene

Here's what I did:

```
String textField1 = fastVectorHighlighter.getBestFragment(fastVectorHighlighter.getFieldQuery(query), indexReader, docId, SearchItem.FIELD_TEXT_FIELD1, DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_LENGTH);
```

Here's the `query`:

```
((FIELD_TEXT_FIELD1:十五*)^4.0) (FIELD_TEXT_FIELD3:十五*)
```

The original text is correct(`indexReader.document(docId).get(SearchItem.FIELD_TEXT_FIELD3)` is correct.), and definitely contains characters in `query`.

Here's how I index textField1 :

```
Field textField1 = new TextField(SearchItem.FIELD_TEXT_FIELD1, "", Field.Store.YES);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

It turns out, I need to change

```
fastVectorHighlighter.getFieldQuery(query)
```

to

```
fastVectorHighlighter.getFieldQuery(query, indexReader)
```

Follow the code into `FieldQuery#flatten`, we will find Lucene doesn't deal with `PrefixQuery` the normal way：

```
} else if (sourceQuery instanceof CustomScoreQuery) {
      final Query q = ((CustomScoreQuery) sourceQuery).getSubQuery();
      if (q != null) {
        flatten( applyParentBoost( q, sourceQuery ), reader, flatQueries);
      }
    } else if (reader != null) {  // <<====== Here it is!
      Query query = sourceQuery;
      if (sourceQuery instanceof MultiTermQuery) {
        MultiTermQuery copy = (MultiTermQuery) sourceQuery.clone();
        copy.setRewriteMethod(new MultiTermQuery.TopTermsScoringBooleanQueryRewrite(MAX_MTQ_TERMS));
        query = copy;
      }
      Query rewritten = query.rewrite(reader);
      if (rewritten != query) {
        // only rewrite once and then flatten again - the rewritten query could have a speacial treatment
        // if this method is overwritten in a subclass.
        flatten(rewritten, reader, flatQueries);

      }
```

We can see it needs a `IndexReader` for `PrefixQuery`, `FuzzyQuery` etc.